# Maven not able to inherit repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

My project is structured like this.

```
Artifact A
|- depends on hadoop-client.jar
|- cloudera repository is added to pom
```

pom.xml

```
 <repository>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <releases>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>libs-release</name>
    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
</repository>
```

Now, A compiles fine, has been packaged as jar and pushed to artifactory (jfrog one)

```
Artifact B
|- depends on A
|- doesn't have cloudera repo in pom
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact_a</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Artifact B is not able to use repo which was added in A and gives error on compilation.

```
"Could not find artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.2.0"
```

Am i missing anything ? 
Don't want to add cloudera repo in pom of Artifact B.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your `pom.xml`.

Comment: what is the scope of A in B's pom.xml?

Comment: @MustafaGenç, haven't added scope, so it think it's taking default one.

Comment: read this : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: @MustafaGenç i know this. which part you are referring here ?

Comment: Importing Dependencies

Comment: Can you care to explain how it will work ? Tried scope:import and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Maven does only inherit repository information from parent POMs, but not from dependencies.
You can create a third POM C which declares the repository and from which A and B inherit - that will work.

Fell into the same pit a while back… ;)

Comment: But isn't it the same thing even if we create a third pom C ? A/B will have to inherit repo info from C

Comment: There are two mechanisms in Maven: 1) inheritance from a parent pom, 2) dependency on another artifact. Repos are inherited via 1) but not via 2). 1) is set in the <parent> element, while 2) is set in a <dependency> element.